# user-defined payments magento

Tags: magento, user-defined-functions

Is is possible for Magento to allow user-defined payments for a product?  Allowing them to under-pay or over-pay when purchasing an item that requires payments?

The product is a TOUR, not an actual product.  Although we have pre-set amounts due, they vary from tour to tour and the same percentage is not charged for each tour.  We need to have Magento accept various payments and dates for each tour.  Allowing participants to make user-defined payments when necessary (more or less than amount due).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box and you would need to build a custom payment module. Making future payments will be a difficult task to get magento to do so I would personally not go down this route.

I dont quite follow your example regarding the tour but if I do follow it you could do the following;

Add a new product attribute called tour date to default attribute set and place it under general. Make this attribute a date field.

Setup a new product for every tour and date combination with unique price and sku (dont forget to select the correct date value from your new tour date attribute). Sets these to not be visible so they dont appear in search or catalogue.

For each tour you can then create a configurable product using the tour date as the configurable attribute when prompted. For each configurable product, under associated products you can select the products (different dated tours) for that tour as the options.

This will basically allow the user to select a date for the tour on the product page and be presented with the correct tour price which you can customise from date to date, tour to tour.

[This video](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=magento%20configurable%20products&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQtwIwAg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DK6LIBBxepk&ei=l0G1UNnDFYm90QXyz4HwDg&usg=AFQjCNG9Y5U606PQ9lsmEzwCBp5vnCWtMQ) will show you how to do this